# Dhrystone2i.apk does not run ARMv8 benchmark

Tags: benchmarking, arm64

I installed Dhrystone2i.apk from http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%2064%20bit%20benchmarks.htm . The website claims it will run 64-bit when supported. I installed on a board which has 4x Cortex-A53 running Android 6.0. It only runs ARMv7 32-bit Dhrystone. What needs to happen to make the benchmark run the ARMv8 64-bit Dhrystone?

Comment: I think this is best answered by roy@roylongbottom.org.uk.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel is 32 bit, the same as my new (now Lenovo) Moto 4G phone with Cortex-A53.  I also have a Lenovo Tab 2, with Cortex-A53, that runs 64 bit benchmarks. On system details provided by the benchmark, the only difference is that the latter CPU and architecture are identified as AArch64, compared ARMv7 or 7. The tablet also indicates AArch64 when running 32 bit only benchmarks. The Linux version code does not appear to identify 32 or 64 bits.